# What does "&q=%s" mean at the end of a Google search URL?

Tags: google-search

What does the `&q=%s` mean (and do) at the end of a Google custom search URL like `http://www.google.com/search?q=@@@&tbs=qdr:y&q=%s`?

Background: I'm using Anysearch Safari Extension (https://github.com/mcs07/AnySearch-safari-extension) and defining a custom search engine (using the url above) to return only results for the past year straight from my Safari menu bar. Using this setup, it seems to work without the `&q=%s` at the end, but not with it.

Comment: It's a query string. What it does is any thing the developer wants to do with it... What if does in Google today may be different tomorrow

Comment: The URL has errors becuse ir includes `q=` two times. What Is the source of such URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is less about what it does for Google and more about what it is doing to your search.  % is generally a wildcard character used in SQL to mean 'A substitute for zero or more characters'.  The plugin may or may not be trying to parse the % character as a wildcard.  % is also an url encoding character so if you perform a Google search on say '**?me on this**' the URL string will look like 'q=**%3Fme+on+this**'.  So the plugin may also be trying to parse it as a URL encoding character.